# Update using onclick

Tags: ajax, laravel

I've been trying to create an update status for only one value in my database which is `isdisabled` from 0 to 1 by using a AJAX onclick. Here are my codes:

index.blade.php :

```
$('body').on('click', '.disableMediaOrder', function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    confirm("Are you sure you want to disable this ?");

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('media-order.disable') }}"+'/'+id,
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data){
            tableMediaOrder.draw();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = MediaOrder::get();
        return DataTables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action',function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="editMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">Edit</a>';

                       $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</a>';

                       $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="disableMediaOrder"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm disableMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">Disable</a>';

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
    } else {
        $groups = Group::all();
        $media_order = DB::table('media_order')->get();
        $moo = MediaOrder::orderBy('nomor','asc')->get();
        $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('media-order.index')->with(compact('users','moo','groups'));
    }
}

public function disable(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT media_order ON');
    MediaOrder::updateOrCreate(['id'=> $request->id],
        [
            'isdisabled' => 1,
        ]);
    DB::unprepared('SET IDENTITY_INSERT media_order OFF');

    if ($request->ajax()){
        return redirect_ajax_notification('media-order.index');
    }else{
        return redirect_ajax('media-order.index');
    }
}
```

And here is my route:

```
Route::post('/MediaOrder/disable', 'MediaOrderController@disable')->name('media-order.disable');
```

And sadly it comes up with 'NotFoundHTTPException;' maybe someone can assist me in solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a 404 because you are using a URL which has no route set up:

```
url: "{{ route('media-order.disable') }}"+'/'+id,
```

This generates a URL like `/MediaOrder/disable/X`.  But you have no route matching that, the one you have will work for `/MediaOrder/disable`.

Update your route like this:

```
Route::post('/MediaOrder/disable/{id}', 'MediaOrderController@disable')->name('media-order.disable');
```

And update your JS like this (simple option, without using `route()`):

```
url: "/MediaOrder/disable/" + id,
```

If you want to use `route()` to generate the URL, you need to do a more complex substitution, since we can't access the JS `id` variable from within Blade `{{ }}`.  You can try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.disableMediaOrder', function(){
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    confirm("Are you sure you want to disable this ?");

    // First generate the route with a dummy text placeholder
    let url = "{{ route('media-order.disable', ['id' => ':id']) }}";

    // Now replace the placeholder with the real value
    url = url.replace(':id', id);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: hello thank you so much for the help!, it trully eliminates the 404 error, and i just figured out the update error by myself and it finally works, this is trully helpfull, thanks again!